# QDox Parser: Get line numbers of comment before a class

Tags: java, parsing, qdox

I am using QDox Parser to analyze .java files and I want to get the line numbers of the comment before the beginning of the class. Unfortunately, I didn't get it with DocletTag class of QDox parser. I only get named Tags but no line numbers.

Sample class:

```
1 /* 
2  * Sample class
3  *
4  *
5  */
6 
7  package org.example.package;
8
9  /**
10  * Looking for the beginning and end of this comment
11  */
12 public class Value {
13   ...
14 }
```

What I am looking for is a method to extract the beginning an end of the comment.

In this example: **line 9** and **line 11**

Answer (score 0):

QDox only works with the start, not with the end. If there's really a need for this, we could introduce something like a JavaDoc-element to the Model, though I'm not sure why anybody would want that kind of info.